# Spring Boot Admin: Either health or status endpoint must be enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I got an error when a running client service.

```
018-09-29 16:10:49.072 ERROR 14815 --- [gistrationTask1]         o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either health or status endpoint must be enabled!
```

there is my client application.properties

```
server.port = 8090
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8010
spring.application.name=xxx
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include="*"
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.password=admin
```

and my server application.properties

```
server.port = 8010
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin
```

I just follow the [Reference Guide](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.0/#getting-started) and nothing works

Comment: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*, this works